# Two UINavigationControllers side-by-side on iPad iOS 4 without UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk, ios4, xamarin.ios

How can I create an interface like the settings app on the iPad where the left side does not collapse as does in the UISplitViewController?

I need to create a UI where the left (master if you will) is a UITableViewController and the right pane (detail) is a UINavigationController.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I had a UI previously using a UISplitViewController but as of iOS 4 on the iPad regardless of what I do it hides the master (left) view.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to check out Matt Gemmell's [MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad).

Comment: Thanks but I'm using MonoTouch

Comment: I hear ya Neal, 'cause I'm a monotouch guy as well. However, if you want to get the most from monotouch, you have to be willing to interpret objective-c code into C#. It takes practice, but it gets easy.

Comment: Old post, but maybe it helps: I have ported MGSplitViewController to Monotouch. It is called MTSplitViewController and can be found at https://github.com/Krumelur/MTSplitViewController

Answer (score 0):

u can do this by taking two layers, i.e, divide your screen(view) into 2 layers by setting the frames. Now, u can do what ever you want with them since they are 2 independent views.

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for [APSplitViewController](https://github.com/slatvick/APSplitViewController/blob/master/Split/APSplitViewController.m)